# My discord bot code is working but is not responding to my commands

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am a junior in programming. I know node.js and want to write my own bot for discord.

My code which is written below doesn't work.
Can you help me with this?

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const config = require('./config.json');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('message', message=>{
  if(!message.content.startsWith(config.prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if(command === 'ping'){
      message.channel.send('pong!');
  }
})

client.login(config.token);
```

Comment: Can you please also add an error you get when trying to run a bot?

Answer (score 5):

`GUILDS` intent is not enough to receive messages. You will also need `GUILD_MESSAGES` intent for messages:

```js
const client = new Client({ 
  intents: [
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES
  ] 
})
```