# Discord Bot not responding to ping command

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I know some basic python and I decided to try my hand at making a discord bot, but failed to get the bot to respond to a command. I tried changing the '-ping' to 'ping' and tried typing on my discord server:

ping
-ping

but neither did anything. Furthermore,

```
console.log('This does not run');
```

does not show up in console.

I'm not quite sure where I wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
const {Client, Intents} = require('discord.js');
const {token} = require('./config.json');
const client = new Client({intents:[Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS]});
const prefix = '-';



client.once('ready', () => {
   console.log('Bot works');
});


client.on('message', message => {
   console.log('This does not run');
   if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

   const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ */);
   const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

   if(command === '-ping'){
       message.channel.send('pong');
   }
});

client.login(token);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My discord bot code is working but is not responding to my commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69575603/my-discord-bot-code-is-working-but-is-not-responding-to-my-commands)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need the `GUILD_MESSAGES` intent enabled. You can add it to the list of intents in the client constructor, like so:

```js
const client = new Client({intents:[Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES]});
```

Comment: Also, remember to enable the `GUILD_MESSAGES` intent in the developer portal.