# Discord Bot not responding to ping command

Tags: javascript, discord

I finished the code where the bot is supposed to reply back if I type in !ping but it is not replying back to me.

```
const { messageLink } = require('discord.js');
const Discord = require('discord.js')

const client = new Discord.Client({intents:32767});


const prefix = '!';
 
client.on('message', message=>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(config.prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
  
    const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  
    if(command === 'ping'){
        message.channel.send('pong!');
    }
  })
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('TixyBot is online!');
});


client.login('Token')
```

Comment: What is `prefix`? Does the event even fire (debug with a `console.log` line before any other code in the event)? Do you send your ping command in all lowercase? See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord Bot not responding to ping command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70131656/discord-bot-not-responding-to-ping-command)