# Discord bot says "The application did not respond" when using a command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm coding a discord bot and when running `/ping`:

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('ping')
        .setDescription('Replies with Pong!'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        interaction.reply('Pong!');
    },
};
```

Whenever I run `/ping`, the bot says: `The application did not respond`.

The bot is supposed to reply `Pong!`. I've tried readding the bot but that did nothing. I have also tried changing the intents list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord Bot not responding to ping command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70131656/discord-bot-not-responding-to-ping-command)

Comment: Have you deployed the command? Where and how do you call `execute`?

Comment: `return await interaction.reply('Pong!')` you might need to await it.