# how dose the bot.on('messageCreate') discord.js work? the bot wont detect a sent message, trying to make a discord chat bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

*consts and requirements*

```
require('dotenv').config();
const OpenAI = require('openai-api');

// Load your key from an environment variable or secret management service
// (do not include your key directly in your code)
const OPENAI_API_KEY = process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY;
const openai = new OpenAI(OPENAI_API_KEY);  

const Discord = require('discord.js');
const TOKEN = process.env.TOKEN;

const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

const prefix = 'w!';

*on ready*
bot.on('ready', async() => {
    console.log(`${bot.user.tag} is online!`);
    bot.user.setActivity('with the code', {type: 'PLAYING'});
});
```

this is the one being the problem, it won't detect sent messages I've tried a few different ways but nothing, got nothing to do with the server permissions I'm testing on a blank server and node is up to date

```
bot.on('messageCreate', message => {

    if (message.content === 'ping') {
        message.channel.send('pong');
    }
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My discord bot code is working but is not responding to my commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69575603/my-discord-bot-code-is-working-but-is-not-responding-to-my-commands)

Answer (score 0):

For the `messageCreate` event to fire you must have the `DIRECT_MESSAGES` Client intent enabled.

```js
const bot = new Discord.Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES] });
```

Read more on intents [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#gateway-intents)