# My discord bot is not responding even though there is no error

Tags: discord.js

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

const config = require('./config.json');

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log("go");
})

client.on('message', (message) => {

    if(message.content == "ping"){
        message.channel.send("pong");
    }
})

client.login(config.token);
```

There is no error in the code, but when I type ping, the bot does not respond, does anyone know why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My discord bot code is working but is not responding to my commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69575603/my-discord-bot-code-is-working-but-is-not-responding-to-my-commands)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you don't have the [`GUILD_MESSAGES`](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#privileged-intents) intent enabled !

Replace that line :

```js
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });
```

with

```js
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
```

As you can see from the official documentation :

`GUILD_MESSAGES` intent let us have events and one of them is `MESSAGE_CREATE` (emits when a message is created (sent))

[image: Guild messages > Message create]

Answer (score 0):

Since after the new update of discord.js, providing intents is an integral part of Disocrd bots.

```js
    const {Client, Intents, Collection} = require('discord.js')
    const client = new Client({intents:[Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES]})
```